# Fetch data through the reference( foreign key) which is array of objects in loopback through relations

Tags: model, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, loopbackjs

I'm facing problem in retrieving through model relations in loopback(strongloop).

Let's say, I'm having two models..

Model1(Item)

```
{
  "name": "Item",
  ..
  ..
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true
    },
    ....
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Model2(Cart)

```
{
  "name": "Cart",
  ..
  ..
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true
    },
    "details": {
      "type": {
        "itemsData": [
            {
            "itemId": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": true
            },
            "quantity": {
                "type": "number",
                "required": true
            },
            }
        ],
        "required": true
      },
      "id": true,
      "generated": true
    },
    ....
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "itemData": {
      "type": "referencesMany",
      "model": "Item",
      "foreignKey": "details.restaurantId",
      "options": {
        "validate": false,
        "forceId": false
      },
      "scope": {
        "fields": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I know that I can achieve retrieving the data if

(1) I change my schema to store only item ids (itemId) and keep it outside of details object. (or)

(2) I need to store all the item data in the itemData(array of objects- complete item information).

(3) Use populate(joins).

In my case there is scope that item data might change, so I can't use the second one(2).

My direct question is that **is there a way to retrieve the other Model data through the relation**, *if I store foreign key as embedded array of objects*.

Is there any way I can achieve with out changing the schema (or) changing the schema, through model relation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to retrieve the other Model data through the relation, if I store foreign key as embedded array of objects.

I don't think so, loopback relations are primaryKey/foreignKey

> Is there any way I can achieve with out changing the schema (or) changing the schema, through model relation.

Mapping items to carts **can** be accomplished with a [hasManyThrough](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasManyThrough-relations.html) relation which can be generated with a `$ lb relation`.

**Details**

An extra table likely named `CartItem` will need to be created with at least 3 properties `id, cart_id, item_id`.

To link an item to a cart use `PUT /Carts/{CartId}/Items/rel/{ItemId}`.

To get items per cart use `GET /Carts/{CartId}/Items`